error after updating minsdkversion 23 in flutter
i already set minsdkversion to 23 in buildgradle but the error shows as
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 21 cannot be smaller than version 23 declared in library [:firebase_auth] C:\src\otipi\build\firebase_auth\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not 
available in 21

i already tried to set minsdkversion to 23 and done flutter clean, flutter pub get
